# Multiple Jquery script not working

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm new to html/php and trying to get Jquery to work. I have picked these up from tutorials on the web to do a few things. The first 2 scripts handle a popup window whenever a user clicks a button on a page and works perfectly by itself. The 3rd allows me to refresh data on the page without reloading the whole page (ie. loading comments about a product). When I add the 3rd script, it works perfectly fine but it breaks the first 2 items.

The first 2 items has a div window at the bottom of the page. When this stops working, it will show the 2 divs visually on the page and you cannot use the button to open up the overlay. I see that the jquerys are from 2 different websites and I was wondering if this is what is causing the problem?

I greatly appreciate the help with this issue.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please share some relevant code that you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

When you have

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

then you don't required to add, coz `jquery.min.js` is compact version of `jquery.js` (but it is of version 1.3.0 and you already have 1.10.2 on the top of it)

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

also you need to add jquery library `jquery-1.10.2.js` always on the top of other js library. In your case you did correct. so just keep below libs

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you think that since I have "1.3.0" at the bottom (or using it in general) it is superseding the "1.10.2" version? I have tried to run it without it but still has the same issues. I have also tried to remove "min" from it but still nothing.

Comment: please share the html code that you have tried and share screen shot of error. Post a jsfiddle link if possible.

Answer (score 0):

jquery-ui and jquery can live together. However, you shouldn't have both versions of jquery. It wouldn't cause an error per say depending on the code.

Please open up your console in chrome or firefox to see if there are any script errors. This will likely help you debug.

So for your code, you could just do this:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For dev purposes, you might want the non-minified version which can also be found here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: I ran it in chrome and received the follow error, "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". It seems like it cannot see the 2 first jquery scripts when I use the 3rd option in there. The function works perfectly without the 3rd option but causes issues when it is in place. Would I just look for "bla/bla/jquery.js"?

Comment: Can you copy the screenshot somewhere? If you click on the line number, it will show you what's wrong. Take a look at this: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#tracking-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help. Pointing me to "developers.google.com" was very helpful. The issue was, when I used the "1.3.0" script, it would make all the jquerys use that instead of "1.10.2". For me to get around it, I update/downgraded to version "1.7". Now both scripts work perfectly fine. Thanks again.